# Error arg 1 $view null given - when displaying a Symfony form in pieces via form_start, form_widget, form_row, etc

Tags: symfony, twig

When I use `{{ form(group_mapping_form) }}` the form renders, but when I try to access dynamically generated form field names with `{{ form_widget(attribute(group_mapping_form, 'use_code_' ~ group.id)) }}` I get the following error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception TypeError: "Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock():
Argument #1 ($view) must be of type Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, null given
```

**PHP Controller (Partial Code)**

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder();

    $groups = json_decode($response->getContent());
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
      $form->add('use_code_' . $group->id, ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
          'Select One' => [
            'none' => '',
            'A' => 'A',
            'B' => 'B',
            'C' => 'C',
            'D' => 'D',
            'E' => 'E',
            'F' => 'F',
            'G' => 'G',
            'H' => 'H',
            'I' => 'I',
            'J' => 'J',
          ],
        ],
      ]);
    }

    $form->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Submit']);
    $form = $form->getForm();

    return $this->render('group_mapping_form.html.twig', [
      'group_mapping_form' => $form->createView(),
      'groups' => $groups ?: '',
    ]);
```

**Twig File**

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <link href="{{ asset('css/table.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  {% if group_mapping_form is not empty %}
    {{ form_start(group_mapping_form) }}
    <table class="styled-table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Group Name</th>
        <th>Entity Use Code</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% if groups is not empty %}
        {% for group in groups %}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="cell-border">{{ group.name }}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="cell-border">{{ form_widget(attribute(group_mapping_form, 'use_code_' ~ group.id)) }}</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        <tr>
          <td>No Records Found!</td>
        </tr>
      {% endif %}
      </tbody>
    </table>

    {{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
    {{ form_end(group_mapping_form) }}

  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: did you try something like `{{ form_widget(group_mapping_form['use_code_' ~ group.id]) }}`?

Comment: Still getting this error ```[25-May-2023 21:13:29 UTC] [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception TypeError: "Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock(): Argument #1 ($view) must be of type Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, null given, called in /var/www/html/Avalara/avalara_excisetax/var/cache/prod/twig/30/305360bba797befef7ef8bf65a76816d.php on line 123" at /var/www/html/Avalara/avalara_excisetax/vendor/symfony/form/FormRenderer.php line 130```

Comment: Looks to me that `group_mapping_form['use_code_' ~ group.id]` is not defined for one or more groups. I would change the code to `{% for group in groups %}{% if group_mapping_form['use_code_' ~ group.id]|default %}....{% endif %}{% endfor %}` and see which group is undefined. Furthermore, it's not bad to enable twig's debug when developping

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just needed to change `{{ form_widget(form.submit) }}` to `{{ form_widget(group_mapping_form.submit) }}` and that fixed it.